# how to retrieve a value from an object array through JSON parse in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, iphone, json, appcelerator

assume a fake json response,
i have this json string...

```
[{"A":"1","B":{"name":"joe","lastname":"jones"},"COLORS:{"red":"rojo","blue":"azul"},"active":"yes"}]
```

i want to get the name "joe" this is what i thought:
in JAVASCRIPT for an iphone app!!!

```
var json = this.responseText;
var response = JSON.parse(json);

alert("hi " + response.B.name);
//the output should be " hi joe"!!
```

but there is no response.... the alert goes blank...
any help would be apreciated

rupGo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted example has some syntax issues. I assume that was simple an error in your example preparation, and not actually in your code. Corrected and formatted, it looks like:

```
[
    {
        "A": "1",
        "B": {
            "name": "joe",
            "lastname": "jones"
        },
        "COLORS": {
            "red": "rojo",
            "blue": "azul"
        },
        "active": "yes"
    }
]
```

In your response example, 'response' is an array with one item. That item is an object which has property 'B' (among others). So you'd access:

```
response[0].B.name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alert("hi " + response[0].B.name);
```

Your response is an array with an object as its first element